# Custom printer to string

Tags: ocaml, variadic-functions

I defined a custom pretty-printer that takes a message, customise it and prints it:

```ml
let mypp ppf msg =
  Format.fprintf ppf "Hello";
  Format.fprintf ppf msg
```

Now, I wanted to use it to print to a string but since I want to use it multiple times I wanted to put it in a function:

```ml
let myspp msg =
  let _ = mypp Format.str_formatter msg in
  Format.flush_str_formatter ()
```

But I can't write what I want:

```
12 |   let s = myspp "Bleh %s" "world" in
               ^^^^^
Error: This function has type ('a, Format.formatter, unit) format -> string
       It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

Even worse, if I delete the argument:

```ml
let () =
  let s = myspp "Bleh %s" in
  Format.eprintf "---%s---@." s
```

Results in:

```
---Hello: ---
```

The formatting string disappeared.

I know I'm missing something but can't find it. I tried using `kfprintf` but didn't have good results. Maybe I need to change my original function?

It should be noted that if I don't use it in a function it works as wanted:

```ml
let () = 
  mypp Format.str_formatter "Blah %s" "blih";
  Format.eprintf "---%s---@." (Format.flush_str_formatter ())
```

Results in:

```
---Hello: Blah blih---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to run some function after that all format arguments have been provided, the only option is to use `kfprintf`:

```
let to_string msg =
  let b = Buffer.create 17 in
  let ppf = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
  Format.fprintf ppf "Hello: ";
  Format.kfprintf (fun ppf ->
    Format.pp_print_flush ppf ();
    Buffer.contents b
  ) ppf msg

  let s = to_string "%d + %d = %d" 1 2 3
```

It is also better to avoid `Format.str_formatter` since this avoid introducing a global mutable state in your program.

EDIT:

If the important point is to reuse the `mypp` function, the simplest fix is to add a continuation argument to `mypp`:

```
let kmypp k ppf msg =
  Format.fprintf ppf "Hello";
  Format.kfprintf k ppf msg

let to_string msg =
  let b = Buffer.create 17 in
  let ppf = Format.formatter_of_buffer b in
  kmypp (fun ppf ->
    Format.pp_print_flush ppf ();
    Buffer.contents b
  ) ppf msg
```

Comment: I want to reuse my first function to be able to use it with other functions. Here you rewrote `Format.fprintf ppf "Hello: "` in the body of the `to_string` function which does not correspond to what I wanted to do. Is it impossible to do what I want?

Comment: After the edit, this is exactly what I wanted.